# DIY double-pane window renovation technique?

Tags: windows, renovation, condensation

If a double-pane window suffers from only condensation, can a motivated DIYer separate the panes and spacers, clean them, and reassemble?  On a dry day, of course.

Comment: It would have to be a pretty dry day LOL.  Learn how humidity works and you'll be like "holy cow!"

Answer (score 2):

Honestly no! They are filled with condensation drying chemical. You would have to suck out the air too.  It would save you time and it’s inexpensive to go to an independent glass company and they can make you new one for 50 bucks or so.

Comment: Right.  If you're able to access the glass and spacers, it's simple enough to replace that panel with an IGU manufactured by a professional.

Answer (score 1):

Most double pane windows are filled with Argon gas. When the seals go bad, the gas escapes and condensation appears. Gas can be added back if the seals can be replaced. It depends on the type of window.

Answer (score 1):

A friend had condensation on an old double glazed window as the seal had failed.

We drilled two small holes and used a pump to draw air into the window. Then, at the other hole we made an air-dryer using a plastic box filled with those desiccant sachets. Once the condensation had been drawn out we filled the holes. Think he has done it once since but was about 7 years ago.